# html page with textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have textarea which shows only 3 lines at time and uses a scroll bar. Now when I print the html in which I have textarea, it only prints the visible part (i.e. 3 lines only).

I want that when user prints the html page, it should print the entire text inside the text box instead of visible part only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435906/print-when-textarea-has-overflow

Comment: Look into the [@media print rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) - it will allow you to define a style for printing.

Comment: @Sunny
You can do it with help of print css.
add same text as textarea in another div with class, make that div hidden in your style.css and make div visible and textarea hidden in print css

you can check answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this one [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vilaskumkar/53nq4bfo/4/) and press Ctrl+P, you'll see that <textarea> is hidden and <div class="textarea"> is visible.

```
.textarea {
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  textarea {
    display: none;
  }
  .textarea {
     display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: That just works if the textarea content is static.You would need to sync the ´div´ and the ´textarea´ with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a different height for the textarea when you are printing:

```
@media print {
   .selectorOfYourTextarea {
      height: 500px;
   }
}
```

This will make your `textarea` `500px` in height only for the printer. The problem though still is that 500px might not be enough.